# Generate XML file from database - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

can anyone explain me how to create xml file from database using codeigniter.

I like to create simple xml file dynamically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into the [Databse utils class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#xml), it has a `xml_from_result` method that will try to generate xml from any database result objects.

Answer (score 0):

check this CI database utility class will help you to generate xml

[Database Utility Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#xml)

Comment: Yes i did same..but i wanted to know how can i generate xml file without creating file on system, i just want to create xml from db and than parse it///

Comment: for this just do $data = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config); it will return xml data only and you can parse that data